# copying QGraphicsItem from one QGraphicsScene to another, items snap to (0,0)

Tags: c++, qt, drawing, copy-constructor

I am trying to create items in one panel and add to a second panel. In the second panel I want them to be movable (and have context menu). The `AddItem` button should add the item from the RenderArea, to the existing list of items in the `CollectionView` (which may already have been moved)

In the code below, the `ShapeView::addItem()` is supposed to create a copy of the item from the RenderArea (where it can change shape, color etc but is not movable, starts at `(0,0)`), place it in the `CollectionView`, where it is movable. The `RenderArea` holds one item - once added to `CollectionView`, the `RenderArea` item should reset.

What is happening... I can't seem to be able to separate the item from the two classes.

- When I add item, even if the items in
  `CollectionView` have moved, their position resets to `0,0` (or whatever the initial position was in the `RenderArea`; but the adding 
  works properly, the individual item properties are correct, like shape and color; also - `CollectionView` items move, RenderArea item
  doesn't).

I am posting all the relevant code:

```
class Item : public QGraphicsItem
{
    Item() { setFlag(ItemIsMovable, false); }   
    Item::Item(Item &copyItem) {         // copy constructor
        setFlag(ItemIsMovable); 
        setPos(copyItem.pos());    // doesn't seem to work
    QRectF boundingRect() const { return QRectF(-35, -30, 35, 20); }
    void Item::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem */*option*/, QWidget */*widget*/) { 
        painter->drawRect(boundingRect()); }
protected:
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
        QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);
    }
};

class CollectionView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT    
public:
    CollectionView(QWidget *parent = 0);    
    void update();
    QList<Item*> *m_items;
};

CollectionView::CollectionView(QWidget *parent)
    : QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    QGraphicsScene *s = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    s->setSceneRect(-width()/2, -height()/2, width(), height());
    setScene(s);
    setViewportUpdateMode(BoundingRectViewportUpdate);
    m_items = new QList<Item*>();
    scene()->clear();
}

void CollectionView::update()
{
    scene()->clear();
    for(int i = 0; i< m_items->size(); i++)
    {
        Item* item = new Item(*m_items->at(i));
        item->setPos(m_items->at(i)->p);  // doesn't seem to work
        scene()->addItem(item);
    }
    viewport()->update();
}

class RenderArea : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    RenderArea(QWidget *parent = 0);    
public:
    Item* item;
};

RenderArea::RenderArea(QWidget *parent)
    : QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    QGraphicsScene *s = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    s->setSceneRect(-width()/2, -height()/2, width(), height());
    setScene(s);
    setViewportUpdateMode(BoundingRectViewportUpdate);
    item = new Item();
    s->addItem(item);
}

// this is the boss/coordinator class
class ShapeView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ShapeView(QWidget *parent = 0);
    CollectionView *collectionView;
private slots:    // more slots corresponding to more controls
    void addItem();
private:    
    QPushButton *addButton;
    RenderArea *renderArea;
};

ShapeView::ShapeView(QWidget *parent)
    : QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    collectionView = new CollectionView(parent);
    renderArea = new RenderArea(this);
    addButton = new QPushButton(tr("Add Item"));
    connect(addButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addItem()));
}

void ShapeView::addItem()
{   
    Item* item = new Item(*renderArea->item);
    collectionView->m_items->append(item);
    collectionView->update();

    // place a new item on renderarea
    renderArea->item = new Item();
    renderArea->scene()->clear();
    renderArea->scene()->addItem(renderArea->item);
    renderArea->viewport()->update();
}
```

Something is wrong in either the way I copy the item, I just don't know what. I see no reason why, when adding items, the `CollectionView` items all snap to the (0,0) position. Perhaps the issue is in the copy constructor but I can't figure what is wrong.

I hope someone can help give me a hint

**Update**: It seems that the problem is in the  `CollectionView::update()` function... adding a 'delete' at the end of the loop removes the item from the collection... Or in the `ShapeView::addItem()` function... Am I creating copy of the item or just reusing it ?

But how do I create a copy of the item ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption was that there was a connection between the items I paint on QGraphicsScene and their representation (as pointers to the objects). Wrong... In fact I misunderstood what the pointer was pointing at...

I updated the position of the items in my list after mouse move and everything is fine.

```
void CollectionView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    Item *currentItem = (Item*)itemAt(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y());
    if(!currentItem) return;    
    QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(event);   
    m_items->at(currentItem->z)->setPos(currentItem->pos());
}
```

The above fixes the code shown. But it is not the best fix.

The better solution to the problem - **remove my list of items** completely, since QGraphicsScene already holds a copy. (there was one benefit of handling my own list of items - bringForward and sendBackward for items was easier to implement since my z values were equal to item index)